# Restart Frozen X without killing KVM Guests

Tags: centos, libvirt

I have a machine with libvirt and KVM Manager running on it.  The machine I have this running on is CentOS 7 and I have 2 VM's running on it.  X has froze and I can't get anything to work but the mouse movement.  Can't click, nothing.

Is there a way to restart X or KVM manager (?!?) and not kill running VM's?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This is not a crappy Type 2 hypervisor where the VMs are stuck to your desktop. Just nuke X and restart virt-manager; your VMs will not notice, provided you don't restart the whole computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using libvirt & KVM, the lifetime of guests is not tied to your X session. By default the guests use a VNC server as their display. So if you kill your X desktop session, all that happens is your VNC client disconnects. When you log back into your new X session KVM will still there waiting for the VNC client connect again.